# Qt/MySQL++/vector iteration question

Tags: c++, vector, qt4, mysqlpp

I've got a question regarding my vector iteration method within a Qt/MySQL++ project I'm working on at the moment.

I've been using for loops to iterate through them so far, and being quite a beginner at C++, didn't realise that the generally accepted method is to use vector::iterator. I've been trying to see a way I can convert them to this model, but I'm a bit stuck. My code reads as follows:

(connector is an instance of my custom db connection class)

```
mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult res = connector->getResults(searchTerm);
  int stock = res.field_num("stock");
  if(res.num_rows() > 0)
  {
    tblStock->setRowCount(res.num_rows());
    for(size_t i = 0; i < res.num_rows(); i++)
    {
      tblStock->setItem(i, 0,
                        new QTableWidgetItem(QString(res[i][stock].c_str())));
    }
  }
```

My problem is that I can't see a way to just use a vector::iterator instead of the incremental size_t, given that I am using `i` to define where to set the QTableWidgetItem. It definitely seems absurd to use both, though.

Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance for anybody and everybody!

X-T

**UPDATE: Changed my program to use QSql objects, and a tableView, instead of a tableWidget, and it all works wonderfully! Thanks to anybody who took time to read the question!**

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow.  When someone helps you solve a problem, instead of renaming your question to "[solved]", you should actually click the check mark next to the answer that solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it any serious reason you don't use QSql? I think QSqlQueryModel + QTableView can solve your problem without any vectors and iterators. A small example, right from Qt help:

```
QSqlQueryModel *model = new QSqlQueryModel;  
model->setQuery("SELECT name, salary FROM employee");  
model->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Name"));    
model->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Salary"));  
QTableView *view = new QTableView;  
view->setModel(model);  // binding model to view
view->show();
```

You probably have to read something about Qt model/view classes and about QSql to fully understand this example, but this is worth reading. I think you will have no problem reading Qt Reference, it is very detailed.

Comment: Thanks! I'd spotted it, but given I knew MySQL++ quite well, I thought it'd be easier. There's no reason I couldn't switch, though. I'll give it a shot and see where I get! Thanks again!!!